# How to change or set awsui-textarea value in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm recently working on creating an tampermonkey script in order to fast setup configurations in the our system(built with React and AWSUI[t1][1]). That app is built from react 16.13 and now I want to trigger my script to setup some initial value into the text area in the configurations. I did try and research a lot of places to make the value in the textarea(awsui-textarea) accepted by the react app but once I try to submit the form, it shows the error saying the value is undefined.

Please help if any one knows how to do this. Thank you so much!!!

**Screenshot of the text area after executing my script:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/awFCJ.png

**Screenshot of the text area after submitting the form:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4fS0.png

**html DOM element:**

```html
<awsui-form-field initialized="true">
   <div class="awsui-form-field">
      <label class="awsui-form-field-label" awsui-form-field-region="label" for="awsui-textarea-4" id="awsui-textarea-4-label">Plattrs</label>
      <div class="awsui-grid awsui-form-field-controls">
         <div class="awsui-row">
            <div class="awsui-form-field-control col-xxxs-12 col-xs-9" awsui-form-field-region="control">
               <span>
                  <awsui-textarea initialized="true"><textarea class="awsui-textarea" rows="3" id="awsui-textarea-4" name="eligibilitySets.0.eligibilityRules.7.parameters.plattrs"></textarea></awsui-textarea>
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</awsui-form-field>
```

---

**react DOM element:**

```
{
  "label": "",
  "name": "eligibilitySets.0.eligibilityRules.10.parameters.plattrs",
  "onBlur": "ƒ onBlur() {}",
  "onChange": "ƒ onChange() {}"
  "value" : undefined
}
```

---

**My script:**

```js
function addPlattrSelector (plattr) {
    let addSelectorButton = $( "button:contains('Add selector')" );
    addSelectorButton.click();

    let selectorInput = $( "*[placeholder='Choose selector']" );
    selectorInput.focus();

    setTimeout(function(){
        let plattrOptions = $( "span:contains('Plattr Argument')" );
        let mouseDownEvt = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {bubbles: true});
        let mouseUpEvt = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {bubbles: true});
        plattrOptions[plattrOptions.length - 1].dispatchEvent(mouseDownEvt);
        plattrOptions[plattrOptions.length - 1].dispatchEvent(mouseUpEvt);

        let negateButton = $( "*[type='checkbox']" );
        negateButton[negateButton.length - 1].click();

        let textArea = $( ".awsui-textarea" );
        //$(textArea[textArea.length - 1]).focus();
        //$(textArea[textArea.length - 1]).val(plattr);
        //$(textArea[textArea.length - 1]).change();
        setNativeValue(textArea[textArea.length - 1], plattr);

    },500);
}
```

---

**Methods I have tired:**
According to research, it turns out the react has override the setValue of Input/textArea, so when user try to set it manually will automatically override. But here some ways to get around with it:

- Use the Js own property to get back the value setter

```js
function setReactFieldValue(element, value) {
  var prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(element);
  var prototypeValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, "value")
    .set;
  prototypeValueSetter.call(element, value);
  element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
}
```

- Using the valueTracker to setup the react props

```js
function setNativeValue(element, value) {
    let lastValue = element.value;
    element.value = value;
    let event = new Event("input", { target: element, bubbles: true });
    // React 15
    event.simulated = true;
    // React 16
    let tracker = element._valueTracker;
    if (tracker) {
        tracker.setValue(lastValue);
    }
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

- Trying to simulate the keyboard event:

```
const kd = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key:"Enter", code: "Enter", keyCode: 13
});
const ku = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
    bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key:"Enter", code: "Enter", keyCode: 13
});

elem.dispatchEvent(kd);
elem.dispatchEvent(ku);
```

```
ReactTestUtils.Simulate.keyDown(element, {bubbles: true, key: "Enter", keyCode: 13, which: 13});
```

However, none of them worked for my case, I wonder if the aws textarea has some other override way or react 16.13 has fixed this.

Thanks!